# c++: why 0 is displayed as 1.29571e+261

Tags: c++, visualization, double-precision

I am trying to create my first class in c++. I am making file called `geometryitems.cpp` and doing this:

```
using namespace std;

class Point
{
    double x, y, z;
public:
    // constructor
    Point(double x, double y, double z)
        {

        }

    // copy constructor
    Point(const Point& pnt)
        {
            x = pnt.x;
            y = pnt.y;
            z = pnt.z;
        }

    void display()
        {
            cout << "Point(" << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")";
        }
};
```

Then I call it from another file like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "geometryitems.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // initialise object Point
    Point pnt = Point(0, 0, 0);
    cout << "Point initialisation:" << endl;
    pnt.display();

    double t = 0;
    cout << endl << t << endl;

    Point pnt2 = pnt;
    pnt2.display();

    // keep the terminal open
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

`t` is shown as normal 0 but other zeros are some other numbers. I would understand if they were just very-very small numbers but there are also very-very big ones...

Why are the zeros in `Point` shown as such strange numbers? Is there a way to make it looking as normal zeros?

Comment: the displayed value is kind of what uninitialized variables are ... random garbage ;)
like `M M.` stated, your constructor does not assign the values of the class members

Comment: @Zaiborg: what does it mean `x(x)` and so on?

Comment: @Alexandr That's an initializer list.

Comment: @Alexandr yeah or in the Point(x,y,z){this->x = x; ...}

Comment: i dont get the point for downvoting that question ... i bet anyone made that mistake at a certain point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not setting the member variables to any value in your constructor:

```
Point(double x, double y, double z)
{

}
```

You need

```
Point(double x, double y, double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
```

This initializes your data members `x`, `y`, and `z` using the [*constructor initialization list*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

You should also remove your copy constructor. The compiler-synthesized one will do just fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's empty

```
Point(double x, double y, double z)
{

}
```

So, `Point pnt = Point(0, 0, 0);` doesn't initialize anything. Use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). Also you can read more about it [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/).

```
Point(double x, double y, double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z)
{                                  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                   // Initializer list
}
```

That copy-constructor is copying  uninitialized values to another object.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is buggy. The members aren't initialized. Change it to:

```
Point(double x_, double y_, double z_)
: x(x_), y(y_), z(z_)
{
}
```

Comment: You don't need those `_` after identifiers to make the names different.